# How can I keep a field up to date if it can change every second in a react native application where the information arrives via rest api?

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, rest

Similar to how stock market applications do where an index changes every second, that is, if I bring the data through rest api, do I have to consult the rest api every second?

[image]

Comment: The short answer is “yes, you have to continually poll for new data.”  But there could possibly be a better solution using newer technologies like WebSockets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: Or with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events